# How to group a dynamically defined list by the first columns value and calculate average for the rest?

Tags: c#, .net, list, nested-lists

I have a dynamically defined nested string list that will be filled using a .txt;

The typical values of the txt are as follows:

```
EPC1687626298729872,12.4,11.3,6.2 EPC1687626298729872,5,6,2
EPC1687626298729872,8,7.3,4 EPC1687626DDDD29872,11.4,10.3,5.2
EPC1687626DDDD29872,9,16,2 EPC2798272987298798,17,2,2
EPC2987398239879832,11,3,2 EPC9827298729872987,4,5,6
EPC3929873981310091,2,2,2 EPC982733U209309280,4,7,11
```

The values of the first column (starting by EPC) are always required.
What I need to do is to group the rows that have the same EPC (first column values) and average the rest of the values by occurrence.

For example

```
EPC1687626298729872,12.4,11.3,6.2 EPC1687626298729872,5,6,2
EPC1687626298729872,8,7.3,4 EPC1687626DDDD29872,11.4,10.3,5.2
EPC1687626DDDD29872,9,16,2
```

should give

```
EPC1687626298729872, (12.4+5+8)/3, (11.3+6+7.3)/3, (6.3+2+4)/3.
EPC1687626DDDD29872, (11.4+9)/2 ,(10.3+16)/2, (5.2+2)/2
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: I was messing around with 2D arrays but I had a problem with the Nullexception so I moved to dynamic nested lists and got stuck figuring out how to group by the first column without assigning names.
But thanks to the answer below i figured it out. thx anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take advantage of LINQ to go about accomplishing this as it provides numerous methods for grouping, calculating averages and all other sorts of data-manipulation.

**Parse Your Data**

Since you have a series of strings that have both string and numeric data, you'll need to split each of your elements up and then split those individual elements up, that is :

- Split your existing input using spaces and newline characters to give you each element (e.g. `EPC1687626298729872,12.4,11.3,6.2`).
- Then split each of these elements using commas as delimiters to give you your respective values (e.g. `{ Name : EPC1687626298729872, P1 : 12.4, ... }`).

This can easily be done via the [`String.Split()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split(v=vs.110).aspx) method along with LINQ's [`Enumerable.Select()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx) methods, which might look like this :

```
// Separate each of your elements
var elements = input.Split(new string[]{" ", Environment.NewLine},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
                    // Separate each element of the string
                    .Select(x => x.Split(','))
                    // Now you have a series of arrays for each element, so map each 
                    // into an object
                    .Select(x => new {
                            Name = x[0],
                            P1 = Decimal.Parse(x[1]),
                            P2 = Decimal.Parse(x[2]),
                            P3 = Decimal.Parse(x[3])
                    });
```

**Group Your Data**

Once you have all of your elements parsed, now you can group them into objects so that you can calculate your aggregate averages :

- Group each of your elements by their "Name" or "Id" via the [`Enumerable.GroupBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534501(v=vs.100).aspx) method.
- Use the groups to calculate the averages through LINQ's [`Enumerable.Average()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb549067(v=vs.100).aspx) method.

This might look like :

```
// At this point you have all of your elements, so now group them 
// by their names and average
var groups = elements.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                     .Select(x => new { 
                            Name = x.Key, 
                            P1 = x.Average(y => y.P1),
                            P2 = x.Average(y => y.P2),
                            P3 = x.Average(y => y.P3)
                     });
```

At this point, you can just iterate through your results and get what you need :

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. The code works just fine, however is there anyway to convert this Generic<anonymous> to a nested list ?
Here's what I tried so far:
List<Enumerable> groups = Db.GroupBy(x => x.Name)
                    .Select(x => new
                    {
                        Name = x.Key,
                        P1 = x.Average(y => y.P1),
                        P2 = x.Average(y => y.P2),
                        P3 = x.Average(y => y.P3)
                    })
                    .AsEnumerable()
                    .ToList();
Any suggestions?